# no me funciona una variable en mi línea de código

Tags: javascript

estoy aprendiendo el bonito lenguaje de programación "Javascript", estoy aprendiendo sobre funciones y sobre el uso de formularios con funciones en Javascript.

En este ejercicio trato de que cuando ponga un valor numérico después pueda utilizar este número para otra función, el problema es que cuando ejecuto la función "dibujoPorClick" trato de asignarle un valor numérico a la variable "numeroFinal", pero si le pongo "var" antes de "numeroFinal" en la consola no me detecta el valor, pero si se lo quito sí me aparece el valor.

¿Esto por qué sucede?, ¿en qué me equivoqué?

Sé que soy muy novato pero me gustaría seguir aprendiendo y por eso recurro a ustedes.

Saludos.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <input type="text" name="" value="" id="texto_lineas">
    <input type="button" name="" value="A darle!!" id="botoncito">

<script type="text/javascript">

var texto = document.getElementById("texto_lineas");
var boton = document.getElementById("botoncito");
var d = document.getElementById("dibujito");

boton.addEventListener("click", dibujoPorClick);

function dibujoPorClick()
{

 var numeroFinal = parseInt(texto_lineas.value);
 
 document.write ("El número es " + numeroFinal);

};

</script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No entiendo, en donde estas agregando `var`?

Comment: Bienvenido @Alfredo P, en la parte de tu funcion `dibujoPorClick` la variable que estás declarando `numeroFinal` quieres obtener el valor de `texto_lineas` el cuál lo declaraste como var `texto`, cambia esa variable indefinida `texto_lineas` a `texto`.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que quieres es poder utilizar el número que obtienes del input tipo text y utilizarlo en otra función, lo que debes hacer es declarar la variable global así como lo haces con `texto, boton y d`, entonces creo otra función que se va a ejecutar después de que acabe la función `dibujoPorClick` que va a restarle `25` a la variable `numeroFinal`, espero te sirva.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <input type="text" name="" value="" id="texto_lineas">
    <input type="button" name="" value="A darle!!" id="botoncito">

<script type="text/javascript">

var texto = document.getElementById("texto_lineas");
var boton = document.getElementById("botoncito");
var d = document.getElementById("dibujito");

boton.addEventListener("click", dibujoPorClick);

var numeroFinal = "";

function dibujoPorClick()
{

 numeroFinal = parseInt(texto.value);
 
 document.write ("El número es " + numeroFinal);

pasarvariable();

};


function pasarvariable(){

  var resta =  numeroFinal - 25;

    document.write('la resta es '+resta);

}

</script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Y como te lo dije en el comentario, la variable que usas que esta indefinida `texto_lineas` debes cambiarla por la variable que ya definiste que es `texto`, debes de tomar en cuenta esto ya que te marcará error al entrar a tu función, sigue practicando, eso hago yo! :D

Answer (score 1):

Hola te tengo la solucion. Ejecuta el siguiente código. Lo acabo de hacer para ayudarte.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ejemplo</title>
        <meta charset="windows-1252">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="texto_lineas">
        <input type="button" name="" value="A darle!!" id="botoncito" onclick="mostrar()">
    <div id="texto"> </div>
     <script>

         function mostrar(){
                      var mitexto= document.getElementById("texto_lineas").value;

             document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = mitexto;
         }
     </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Le explico un poco.  Lo que pasa es que al colocar document.getElementById().innerHTML  debemos seleccionar en que id va a aparecer el contenido. En este claso cree un div que tenga el id donde va a aparecer en este caso le coloque el nombre "texto". Entonces, en este id vamos a colocar el valor de una variable que capture el valor de su form. Para esto cree una variable llamada mitexto. de la siguiente manera

```
var mitexto= document.getElementById("texto_lineas").value;
```

Colocamos al final `.value` de esta forma la variable captura el valor del contenido del id donde esta el formulario.

Comment: ¿Y por qué es la solución? Podrías explicarle un poco el razonamiento detrás de este código

Comment: Claro.  Le explico un poco.  Lo que pasa es que al colocar document.getElementById().innerHTML  debemos seleccionar en que id va a aparecer el contenido. En este claso cree un div que tenga el id donde va a aparecer en este caso le coloque el nombre "texto". Entonces, en este id vamos a colocar el valor de una variable que capture el valor de su form. Para esto cree una variable llamada mitexto. de la siguiente manera var mitexto= document.getElementById("texto_lineas").value;

Answer (score 0):

tu codigo esta bien, solo deberias fijarte usar la variable que declaras, este caso declaras texto y debes usar el mismo, tambien agregue una pequeña validación para que acepte solo números, dicha validacion puedes hacerla de muchas maneras con

```
isNaN
typeof..etc
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <input type="text" name="" value="" id="texto_lineas">
    <input type="button" name="" value="A darle!!" id="botoncito">




<script type="text/javascript">

var texto = document.getElementById("texto_lineas");
var boton = document.getElementById("botoncito");
var d = document.getElementById("dibujito");

boton.addEventListener("click", dibujoPorClick);


function dibujoPorClick(){
  if(isNaN(texto.value)){
    texto.value =null;
    alert('ingrese un numero !!');
    return false;
   }else{
    var numeroFinal = parseInt(texto.value);
    document.write ("El número es " + numeroFinal);
   }
 }//end function dibujoPorClick

</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Tambien uso una linea:

```
texto.value =null;
```

Esto sirve para limpiar el input donde ingresa el texto.

Espero te sirva y sigue adelante..!!